# Float sections of LI items inside a UL with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-float

I have a series of LI inside a UL like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="section left"></li>
    <li>I want to float this on the left</li>
    <li>I want to float this on the left</li>
    <li>I want to float this on the left</li>
    <li class="section right"></li>
    <li>I want to float this on the right</li>
    <li>I want to float this on the right</li>
    <li>I want to float this on the right</li>
</ul>
```

This HTML is generated by php and I cannot alter the HTML, on the other hand I have the ability to assign classes to individual LI elements. The UL and LIs will contain form elements, which I want to distribute in two sections, floating some contents (some LIs) on the left and some content (other LIs) on the right.

If I could nest ULs within the main UL this would be much easier, treating inner ULs as blocks, but I can't do that here.

How to accomplish the same result with CSS given the HTML constraints mentioned above? I mean yeah I could assign floating classes individually to each LI but I was hoping to a more elegant solution here.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS3 code:

```
ul{width:100%;list-style:none;}
/* the '~'  (general sibling combinator)
 * selector will select all following siblings in the document tree.
 * This selector is part of the CSS3 selector recommendation,
 * see also http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators
 *
*/
li.section.left, li.section.left ~ li{
    background-color:#faa;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1em;
}
li.secton.right , li.section.right ~ li{
    background-color:#afa;
    float:right ;
    margin-left:1em;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Use this with your proposed code and you'll get what you need (at least in decent browsers). [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5DdC/) / [Demo with small font size](http://jsfiddle.net/q5DdC/1/) (to see effect)

**Update:** [IE7+ compatible version](http://jsfiddle.net/q5DdC/2/) (simply without `:not`)

Comment: nice css, but this will break lots of browsers! esp. <IE10 -.-

Comment: @Christoph: Should work on at least IE9. If you strip `:not` (not necessary, as stated above), it works on IE7+, FF3+ Saf4+, Chrome4+ Opera10.10+... (see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t30)

Comment: I'll bet my grandma, that sibling combinator won't work in IE7! It would destroy my whole picture of IE;)

Comment: Please test the code above in IE7, make a screenshot and post it to quirksmode :D. But I'll don't believe it either, since IE7 [can't handle](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t12) the next sibling selector `+`... But in case we're both wrong... Poor granny. Gonna work hard in the Microsoft mines :D.

Comment: well, perhaps my granny working there would be a good thing, and MS eventually catches up in browserdevelopment with her as CTO >.<

Comment: @Yoeri: See [CSS level 3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) and the [quirskmode compatibility charts](http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) (css 4 not yet included).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how exactly you want the list to look... But, *if you can assign a **right** class to the list items*, you can set the CSS along the lines shown below to position them:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        li {width:300px; list-style-position:inside;}
        li.right {background:pink; text-align:right; direction:rtl;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li class="right">Item 3 -- right</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li class="right">Item 5 -- right</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, bit hard.
Is the amount of elements fixed?

If so, first thing that comes to thought is using the adjacent sibling selector (+).

```
li.section.left,
li.section.left + li,
li.section.left + li + li,
li.section.left + li + li + li {
    float: left
}
```

Same for the float-right elements ...
Otherwise, I would try and use jquery to get to the elements and assign classes to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to this, is creating the list that you have like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>I want to float this on the left</li>
        <li>I want to float this on the right</li>
        <li>I want to float this on the left</li>
        <li>I want to float this on the right</li>
        <li>I want to float this on the left</li>
        <li>I want to float this on the right</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS you give all LI a float left and style them.(I mean width, height and so on)
After that build a little div around it and give it a max with you want you form to be (be sure the LI fit within it in rows of 2.)

This could be a solution but i don't know how much of the HTML you can alter.